# Remove zero values from a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a normal array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 150
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 100
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 100
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 100
    [8] => 50
    [9] => 100
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 100
    [12] => 0
    [13] => 100
    [14] => 0
    [15] => 100
    [16] => 0
    [17] => 100
    [18] => 0
    [19] => 100
    [20] => 0
    [21] => 100
)
```

I need to remove all 0's from this array, is this possible with a PHP array function

Answer (score 105, accepted):

[`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) does that. If you don’t supply a callback function, it filters all values out that equal *false* ([boolean conversion](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)).

Comment: Nice solution. I suppose my answer remains useful for anyone who has this issue but the value to remove is non-zero.

Comment: A callback can be used with array_filter() for when the filtering needs to be customised.

Answer (score 12):

bit late, but copy & paste:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($a) { return ($a !== 0); });
```

Answer (score 8):

You can just loop through the array and unset any items that are exactly equal to 0

```
foreach ($array as $array_key => $array_item) {
  if ($array[$array_key] === 0) {
    unset($array[$array_key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: its not working if use ===, buts working if i use ==

Comment: I wouldn't write `$array[$array_key]` inside the condition, I'd write `$array_item` because it is simpler.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this:

```
$result = array_diff($array, [0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

**First Method:**

```
<?php
    $array = array(0,100,0,150,0,200);
    
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";
    
    foreach($array as $array_item){
            if($array_item==0){
               unset($array_item);
        }
        echo"<pre>";
        print_r($array_item);
        echo"</pre>";
    }
?>
```

**Second Method:** Use [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function

```
  <?php
    $array = array(0,100,0,150,0,200);
    $remove = array(0);
    $result = array_diff($array, $remove);                          
    echo"<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo"</pre>";
  ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($a) { return ($a !== 0); });"
```

if you want to remove zero *AND* empty values, the right code is:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($a) { return ($a !== 0 AND trim($a) != ''); });
```

Comment: Some tests for the second snippet: https://3v4l.org/cc2vm

Comment: Stray " at the end of your first line.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about preserving key to data correlations, you can use this single line trick :

```
<?php
$a = array(0, 150, 0, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100);

$b = explode('][', trim(str_replace('[0]', '', '['.implode('][', $a).']'), '[]'));

print_r($b); // Array ([0] => 150 [1] => 100 [2] => 100 [3] => 100)
```

Comment: This is not optimized, but +1 for your try!