# remove zero occurrence in array

Tags: php, arrays, time

I am implementing a function to calculate date. the function makes the calculations to find each element: **year, month, week, day, hour, minute, second**.

the result of the calculation is an array like this:

```
array (
     [year] => 0
     [month] => 0
     [week] => 0
     [day] => 0
     [hour] => 3
     [minute] => 193
     [second] => 11583
)
```

must now remove any occurrence that is **KEY = 0**, and leave only the indices **hour, minute, second**.

there's some native PHP function that can do this?

Thank you all

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove zero values from a PHP array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287404/remove-zero-values-from-a-php-array)

Comment: Instead of removing zero keys make date function not to return 0 value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_filter ( array $input);
```

Should work. It will delete all elements with value equals to false.
If you would like all elements that are === 0 create your own callback function for array_filter like in the link below.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php