# Sort array of numbers from lowest but eliminate zero and empty values using php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

**NOTE:** *I am sorry if this question has been asked. but the ones that have been asked and answered do not directly address the condition in my question. that is why i have asked it.*

I have this code that sorts my list from lowest value to highest value and then it sums the first three
**But the variables keep changing**

```
<?php $zero = 0; $one = 1;  $two = 2; $three = 3; $four = 4;   ?>
<?php 
    $arr = array($zero,$one,$two,$three,$four);
    asort($arr);                    // sort ascending, lowest first
    $tre = array_slice($arr, 0, 3);  // first three
    $sum = array_sum($tre);          // summed up
?>

<div id="result"><?php echo $sum; ?></div>
```

What this code does, is that it sums up the first three numbers in ascending order including the zero i.e.

**0+1+2 = 3**

But that is not what i want, I would want it to sum up the first three numbers in ascending order but to ignore the zeros i.e. in my case

**1+2+3 = 6**

in addition: *if a code can eliminate zero and also an empty value, it could be much better* but not necessary

Any help on how i could go about this?

Comment: You can use `array filter` as this clever [gentleman](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2287415/5473628) pointed out.

Comment: @peaceman but it does not directly answer my question. I had looked at it earlier but i am sorry i could not understand  it. that is why i had to ask the question.

Comment: use it like this $arr = array_filter($arr) if you just supply it with an array it will filter out the values equal to false. 0 is equal to false so zeros will be filtered out.

Comment: @Anant i have. You have helped me a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First why to create so much variables,just create an array with values directly (i showed in my example)**

**You can remove your `0` value from array using `array_filter()`:-**

```
  <?php 
    $arr = array(0,1,2,3,4);

    $arr = array_filter($arr);      // remove 0 values
    asort($arr);                    // sort ascending, lowest first
    $tre = array_slice($arr, 0, 3);  // first three
    $sum = array_sum($tre);          // summed up
?>

<div id="result"><?php echo $sum; ?></div>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/534727

Reference:- http://php.net/array_filter

**Or Just change in your code`array_slice($arr,1,3)` (BUT IT WILL WORK ONLY WHAT THE CODE YOU SHOWN TO US NOT IN OTHER CASES):-**

```
<?php 
    $arr = array(0,1,2,3,4);
    asort($arr);                    // sort ascending, lowest first
    $tre = array_slice($arr, 1, 3);  // first three
    $sum = array_sum($tre);          // summed up
?>

<div id="result"><?php echo $sum; ?></div>
```

Output:-https://eval.in/534704

Comment: Does `array_filter($arr);` automaticaly eliminate the zeros

Comment: What if you've more 0 in array.. You're first example fails in that case. array_filter works fine in that case.

Comment: <?php
$arr = array(0,1,2,0,0,3,4);
asort($arr);                    // sort ascending, lowest first
$tre = array_slice($arr, 1, 3);  // first three
$sum = array_sum($tre);
echo $sum;    Try array_slice code using $arr = array(0,1,0,0,2,1,4); and let me know the answer please

Comment: I was talking about another one dear in which you said you can do array_slice($arr, 1,3); i already said that your array_filter works fine in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
<?php
$arr = array(1,3,45,2,7,0,1,0);
echo removeZeroAndSumFirstThree();

function removeZeroAndSumFirstThree($arr) {
    asort($arr);
    //Remove 0 from array
    $a = array_diff($arr, array(0));
    $output = array_slice($a, 0, 3);
    return array_sum($output);
}
```

Comment: why custom code if already an inbuilt function can do that `array_filter();`

Comment: I think you missed argument of function. Giving error while calling function https://3v4l.org/AIU2F

Comment: For php < 5.4 define array in traditional manner i.e. $var = array(..) to avoide syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would write a helper function that iterates through the array that is re usable:

```
<?php

public function sumFirstNonZeros($array){
    $countAdded = 0;
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($array as $number){
        if($countAdded<3){
            if($number > 0){
                $sum = $sum + $number;
                $countAdded = $countAdded + 1;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return $sum;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array($zero,$one,$two,$three,$four);
asort($arr);                    // sort ascending, lowest first
$sum = $i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $num) {

    if($num != 0) {
        $sum == $sum + $num;
        $i++;
    }
    if ($i == 2) {
        break;
    }
}
echo $sum;
```

or you can try this

```
$arr = array($zero, $one, $two, $three, $four);
asort($arr);                    // sort ascending, lowest first

$sumArr = array();
foreach ($arr as $num) {
    if ($num != 0) {
        $sumArr[] = $num;
        if (count($sumArr) == 3) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
echo array_sum($sumArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

More universal solution:

EDIT:

Correct one:

```
$zero = 0; $one = 1;  $two = 2; $three = 3; $four = 4;  

$arr = array($zero,$one,$two,$three,$four);
asort($arr);                    // sort ascending, lowest first
$total = 0;
$i = 0;

foreach ($arr as $v)
{
    if ($i < 3)
    {
  if ($v != 0)
  {
    var_dump($v);
    $total += $v;
    $i++;
  }
    }
}

echo $total;
```

Comment: @Qrzysio thanks so much, that could be of some help to me at some scenario

Comment: Please rate my answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use array_filter() function to remove zero values from array before the sum.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php