# How to get the product of an array without multiplying the zeros in php

Tags: php

I have an array : `[1, 4, 3, 0, 5]` and the output I want is `60` Which is to get the product of the array without multiplying the zeros in php. But I'm having struggles on figuring it out. Does anyone know how to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove zero values from a PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287404/remove-zero-values-from-a-php-array)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Sorry, It doesn't answer my question. I don't want to remove the 0's. I just want to get the product without multiplying the zero's, if that makes sense.

Comment: yeah , but first you need to create temporary array without zero, then multiply it

Comment: Sure it does - use `array_filter()` (or any of the answers in that question) to strip the zeros, then multiply the rest of the elements. Someone has already posted an answer posted here doing exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to compute the product, comparing the intermediate values with `0` before multiplication:

```
$array = [1, 4, 3, 0, 5];

$product = array_reduce($array, function ($c, $v) { return $c * ($v == 0 ? 1 : $v); }, 1);
echo $product;
```

Output:

```
60
```

Or alternatively, use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove the `0` values and then use [`array_product`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-product.php) on the result (note this does not modify the original array):

```
$product = array_product(array_filter($array));
echo $product;
```

Output:

```
60
```

Also note that since you only want to remove `0` values, which are `false` in a boolean context; you don't need a callback function for `array_filter`.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/5N9qN)

Comment: `array_product(array_filter($array));` - very nice

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. You can use `array_reduce` function and pass `1` for base multiplication.

```
function multiply($carry, $item){
  if($item != 0){
    $carry *= $item;
  }
  return $carry;
}
$array = [1,4,3,0,5];
var_dump(array_reduce($array,'multiply', 1)); // int(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` to remove the zero from an array.

```
function exclude_zero($var)
  {
   if($var != 0)
   {
   return $var;
   }
  }

$a1=[1, 4, 3, 0, 5];
$result = [];
$result[] = array_filter($a1,"exclude_zero");
$result = array_product($result[0]);
echo $result;
```

**Output**

```
60
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can loop through the array and multiply the values in it if the value is not 0.

   ```
    $arr = [1, 4, 3, 0, 5];
    $value = 1;
    foreach($arr as $val){
        if($val !== 0){
            $value *=$val;
        }
       }
    echo $value; 
    //this will return 60
   ```
2. You can use a combination of `array_product` and `array_filter` to get your answer.

   ```
   $product = array_product(array_filter($array));
   echo $product;
   //this will return 60.
   ```